# AngularFire7 Maximum call stack exceeded in transaction

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I've already made a post but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72763167/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-angularfire-7?noredirect=1#comment128541059_72763167) got closed. I also found  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70490556/onvalue-somehow-causing-error-error-uncaught-in-promise-rangeerror-maximu)  which is pretty much the same error I got.

Now I got the same error for another reason and still can't find any answers on the net. I'm using the realtime database and I have a node in the database that looks like this:

```
private: {
  $user_uid: {
    formula: {
      formula_quota:30,
      quota_used:0
    }
  }
}
```

I use a button to publish some data and run a transaction to get the quota object and update it when publish is done.

I won't post the code that is not used or commented out but the quota transaction is like that:

```
quotaTransaction ( userUID:string, projectUID:string, state:EditorState, asObject:boolean, asProject:boolean ) {

    const quotaPath = `/private/${ userUID }/formula`;

    const quotaDoc = ref( this.db, quotaPath );
 
    runTransaction( quotaDoc, quota => {

      let nbPublish = 0;

      if ( asObject ) nbPublish++;
      if ( asProject ) nbPublish++;

      let quotaUsed = quota.quota_used;
      let formulaQuota = quota.formula_quota;

      if ( nbPublish + quotaUsed > formulaQuota ) return ( undefined );

      return ( { quota_used: quotaUsed + nbPublish, formula_quota:formulaQuota } );

    } ).catch( console.log );

}
```

the first time I run the quotaTransaction I get this error

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
> at ChildrenNode.isLeafNode (vendor.js:52413:13)
> at ChildrenNode.equals (vendor.js:20990:22)
> at ChildrenNode.equals (vendor.js:20995:31)
> at ChildrenNode.equals (vendor.js:20995:31)
> at ChildrenNode.equals (vendor.js:20995:31)
> at ChildrenNode.equals (vendor.js:20995:31)
> at ChildrenNode.equals (vendor.js:20995:31)
> at ChildrenNode.equals (vendor.js:20995:31)
> at ChildrenNode.equals (vendor.js:20995:31)
> at ChildrenNode.equals (vendor.js:20995:31)

second time I run it I get:

> TypeError: childPathObj.split is not a function
> at pathChild (vendor.js:17766:38)
> at ImmutableTree.findRootMostMatchingPathAndValue (vendor.js:23435:30)
> at ImmutableTree.findRootMostMatchingPathAndValue (vendor.js:23432:51)
> at ImmutableTree.findRootMostMatchingPathAndValue (vendor.js:23432:51)
> at ImmutableTree.findRootMostValueAndPath (vendor.js:23456:17)
> at compoundWriteGetCompleteNode (vendor.js:55532:45)
> at compoundWriteChildCompoundWrite (vendor.js:55574:27)
> at writeTreeCalcCompleteEventCache (vendor.js:55887:19)
> at syncTreeCalcCompleteEventCache (vendor.js:57565:10)
> at repoGetLatestState (vendor.js:59219:10)

Any clue, maybe the firebase team can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downgrading to version `7.4.0` instead of `7.4.1` apparently solved the issue.